# react-leaflet , when a country is selected I want to highlight that country borders

Tags: leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet

I am trying to use geoJson layer and pass it the selectedCountry .

I get this error : "**BordersGeoJSON.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'geoJSON')**"
I have checked that selectedCountry is a valid geoJSON object.  The console log looks like this:

> {type: 'Feature', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
> geometry
> :
> {type: 'Polygon', coordinates: Array(1)}
> properties
> :
> {name: 'Ireland', iso_a2: 'IE', iso_a3: 'IRL', iso_n3: '372'}
> type
> :
> "Feature"
> [[Prototype]]
> :
> Object

My code is this:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { L } from 'leaflet';

const BordersGeoJSON = ({mapRef, selectedCountry}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef && selectedCountry) {
        console.log(selectedCountry)
      const layer = L.geoJSON(selectedCountry, {
        style: () => ({ color: "red" }),
      });
      layer.addTo(mapRef.leafletElement);
    }
  }, [mapRef, selectedCountry]);

  return null;
};

export default BordersGeoJSON
```

1. I have tried to use selectedCountry geometry only but I get the same error
2. I have tried using directly the geoJSON file instead of selectedCountry but I get the same error

**Here it is on sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-galois-7y1xd3?file=/src/components/leaflet/BasicMap/PointsOfInterest.js**

Comment: Could you create a demo to reproduce this with codesandbox or sth similar?

Comment: I have updated the post with the sandbox link . Here it is as well       https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-galois-7y1xd3?file=/src/components/leaflet/BasicMap/PointsOfInterest.js

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

I have changed things to use GeoJson component and use the selectedCountry state. GeoJson needs a key to update every time selectedCountry changes .

here is the code :

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet';


const BordersGeoJSON = ({bounds, selectedCountry}) => { 
  const [geoJsonKey, addToGeoJsonKey] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    addToGeoJsonKey(geoJsonKey + 1)
  }, [selectedCountry])

  return (
    <>
    { selectedCountry && 
      <GeoJSON
        key={geoJsonKey}
        data={selectedCountry}
        style={() => ({ color: 'blue' })}
        
      />
    }
    </>    
  );
};

export default BordersGeoJSON
```